# Joining 2 tables using a join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I set up a relationship between the following three tables:  `User`, `Armies` and `User_Armies`

`UserArmies` is my join table, which contains `user_id` and `army_id`

I want to build the following query using active record, but can't figure out how:

```
SELECT ua.number_owned, a.population 
FROM user_armies ua 
INNER JOIN armies a 
ON ua.army_id = a.id 
WHERE ua.user_id = 1;
```

`User` has_many `User_Armies`.  And `Armies` has_may `User_Armies` (just a normal set up using a join table).

Does anyone know the correct active record syntax to do this query!?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UserArmies.joins(:armies, :user).where('users.id = 1').map { |e| { e.number_owned => e.armies.map(&:population) } }
```

Something like that should work...

Comment: it got me on the right track.  I am using: `UserArmy.joins(:army).select("armies.population", :number_owned).where(user_id:1)` which seems to work

Answer (score 1):

User_Armies model:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :armies
```

User model:

```
has_many :user_armies
has_many :armies, through: :user_armies
```

Armies model:

```
has_many :user_armies
has_many :users, through: :user_armies
```

Controller:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@users = @user.armies
```

Comment: Thanks.  This returns all `armies` that a user owns.  But the two pieces I need are the population found in `armies` and the `number_owned` found in `user_armies`.  I need to use both these pieces of info to do a calculation.  So i am storing additional data inside the `join` table.